# How to put values inside a column based on other column values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rvest, data-cleaning

I am working with R to scrape and clean a data for my work as journalist. I could get the table of the HTML, then read it as dataframe and rename the columns' name. Now I am trying to create a new column which gets a value considering other column' values.

This new column should get the values of "Avante", "DEM", "MDB", "Patriota", "PCdoB" and so on. It´s the party of each deputy. Avante, for example, has three deputies, who are "Adalberto Cavalcanti", "Cabo Sabino" and "Silvio Costa". The name of the deputies always come below the whole row with the party´s name.

```r
url <- "http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/votacao/mostraVotacao.asp?ideVotacao=8559&numLegislatura=55&codCasa=1&numSessaoLegislativa=4&indTipoSessaoLegislativa=O&numSessao=225&indTipoSessao=E&tipo=partido"

library(xml2)
library(rvest)
file <- read_html(url)
tables <- html_nodes(file, "table")
table1 <- html_table(tables[3], fill = TRUE, header = T)

head(table1)

table1_df <- as.data.frame(table1)

colnames(table1_df) <- c("deputado", "uf", "voto")
```

This is what I have right now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPtJM.png)

This is what I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe9oZ.png)

Comment: Not clear about what you wanted.  Can you show few lines of expected output

Comment: Ok, I've just added the picture of what I have and what I trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses only base R:

```
url <- "http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/votacao/mostraVotacao.asp?ideVotacao=8559&numLegislatura=55&codCasa=1&numSessaoLegislativa=4&indTipoSessaoLegislativa=O&numSessao=225&indTipoSessao=E&tipo=partido"

library(xml2)
library(rvest)
file <- read_html(url)
tables <- html_nodes(file, "table")
table1 <- html_table(tables[3], fill = TRUE, header = T)

head(table1)

table1_df <- as.data.frame(table1)

colnames(table1_df) <- c("deputado", "uf", "voto")

# create the new column for later
table1_df$new_column <- NA

# identify rows with the Total PARTY: NUM rows
idx <- grep("Total.*: \\d+", table1_df$deputado)

# Loop over these and assign the values
for (i in seq_along(idx)){
  # Extract the number of deputados
  n <- as.numeric(sub("^.*: ", "", table1_df$deputado[idx[i]]))
  # Extract the party
  partido <- sub("Total ", "", table1_df$deputado[idx[i]])
  partido <- sub(": .*", "", partido)
  # Assign the values
  table1_df$new_column[(idx[i] - n):(idx[i] - 1)] <- partido
}

# Remove the unnecessary lines
table1_df <- table1_df[-grep("Total .*:.*", table1_df$deputado), ]
table1_df <- table1_df[-which(table1_df$deputado == table1_df$uf), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another option using `zoo` and `dplyr`.

1) Get the names of the parties.

```
parties <- sub(pattern = "Total\\s(.+):\\s\\d+", 
                replacement = "\\1", 
                x = table1_df$deputado[grepl("Total", x = table1_df$deputado)])
```

2) Add `parties` as new column and carry the last oberservations forword as there are many `NA`s in `parties[match(table1_df$deputado, parties)]`.

```
table1_df$new_col <- zoo::na.locf(parties[match(table1_df$deputado, parties)])
```

3) Delete unneeded rows.

```
library(dplyr)
table1_df <- table1_df %>% 
  group_by(new_col) %>% 
  slice(2:(n()-1))
table1_df
# A tibble: 324 x 4
# Groups:   new_col [24]
#   deputado             uf    voto      new_col
#   <chr>                <chr> <chr>     <chr>  
# 1 Adalberto Cavalcanti PE    Não       Avante 
# 2 Cabo Sabino          CE    Abstenção Avante 
# 3 Silvio Costa         PE    Sim       Avante 
# 4 Alan Rick            AC    Sim       DEM    
# 5 Alberto Fraga        DF    Não       DEM    
# 6 Alexandre Leite      SP    Sim       DEM    
# 7 Arthur Oliveira Maia BA    Sim       DEM    
# 8 Carlos Melles        MG    Sim       DEM    
# 9 Efraim Filho         PB    Não       DEM    
#10 Eli Corrêa Filho     SP    Sim       DEM    
# ... with 314 more rows
```